# Error while connecting a server database from local host

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I want to run PHP script in local system (localhost) and the data to be stored in the server database. I'm getting an error while connecting to remote mysql database from localhost through PHP script.

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'XXXX'@'ip address' (using password: YES) in  E:\xampp\htdocs\New\example\include\config.php on line 13
```

I tried using

```
$con= mysql_connect("example.com:3306","db username","password"); 
mysql_select_db('db', $con);
```

I tried using `mysqli_connect(...)` also but I couldn't connet.

somebody please guide me how can I resolve this?

Comment: confirm correct password ....

Comment: I run this script in server and it connects. So no prob with the password.

Comment: First of all, check your password and username correctly.... secondly... use mysqli or pdo... mysql depreciated....

Comment: Your Localhost password or username may be different then your server password it is a credential error

Comment: Your credentials are definitely not correct. That's what the error message says. If you come from a remote host, you have to set up a user with "username@remote_ip" or "username@%". % is a wildcard, so you can connect from any host - which of course is less secure.

Comment: I uploaded the same script in the server & executed. It connected well. I'm connecting from localhost so, do I need to give the server credential or database credential? I've given the database credential. Is it okay?

Comment: @Raj.A is there allowed remote connection to your database?

Comment: if u are working in local means just `mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');` itself

Comment: Only one accepted host is there.

Comment: @Chris where to set up the user?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running it on Localhost then do it like this

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','username', 'password', 'database');
```

When you use mysqli you don't need to use the `mysql_select_db` as this information is passed in when you create the connection.

The main fix that I will stress here is using your first credential passed into the connect variable as `'Localhost'` if its local on your machine and you are using xampp or mamp etc then use localhost.

this syntax that you have done `mysql_select_db('db', '$con')` is wrong when using mysql you DO NOT need to pass a `$connection` variable into mysql as this only applies for the new `mysqli`.

Last word of advice as soon as your comfortable (preferably asap) move away from mysql functions and use mysqli, the move is not too different you just have to learn where to pass in the `$conn` variables.

Comment: I run the script in local host(xampp) but, I want the data to be stored in remote hosted server (internet server database). I connected using 'mysql_connect("liveserver.com:3306","test","xxxx");' I got the same warning message!!

Comment: noo just use localhost, even when on a webserver i use localhost for the connection, change "liveserver.com" to just "localhost", use the connection syntax i shown in my above answer $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'test', 'password', 'database')or die("Error").

Comment: I get this when I use `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'db username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in E:\xampp\htdocs\business\config.php on line 17`. I have a doubt here that I run the script in xampp. Then how will it connect to the 'server database' when we use `'localhost'`?

Comment: when I run scripts on my web server I use 'Localhost' as the first variable, could you show me your mysqli_connection? plus I would now recommend trying another answer out.

Comment: when I run script on web server it works fine & I'm able to add records. But I want to run the script in my 'local system(PC using xampp)' and the records should be stored in 'web server database'! Pls. So, I think we have to specify the 'Sever Host Name' or 'Host IP Address'. So the syntax may be `mysqli_connect('IP Address:3036', 'DB_User_Name', 'DB Password', 'DB Name')or die("Error");`

Answer (score 0):

Seams like you have not granted privileges to user.

Try this on your remote database.

```
~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter Password:

mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to user identified by 'pass' with grant option;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, check out Kenziiee Flavius answer first - that might already solve your problem as you are on localhost.

Log in to your Server via commandline:

```
mysql -u username -p
```

Create a new user for your remote host:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'192.168.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'192.168.0.1';
```

Replace 192.168.0.1 with the ip or hostname of your remote host.